# Changing frame size in mdframed

Tags: spacing, mdframed, framed

I am trying to place a box around a definition.  Using the package mdframed, I have managed to do so.  However, the box is too large, in particular too tall, and it is covering up text appearing above and below the definition.  I am using

```
\newenvironment{bdefn}    
  {\begin{mdframed}\begin{defn}}    
  {\end{defn}\end{mdframed}}
```

to create the "boxed definition" environment, and then I am using

```
\begin{bdefn}    
(text)    
\end{bdefn}
```

for the definition itself.

I have tried to manually create a new mdframed style to use which has smaller margins, using something like

```
\mdfdefinestyle{style1}{leftmargin=1cm,rightmargin=1cm,skipbelow=1cm,skipabove=1cm}.
```

The command `\mdfdefinestyle` and this format are both taken from the documentation for mdframed.  However, when I place this line into my document's preamble, I receive the error message

```
"Undefined control sequence: \mdfdefinestyle{stlye1}{..."
```

Can anyone tell me why the command `\mdfdefinestyle` is not being recognized?  Or, can anyone suggest a different way to make an as-small-as-possible box around my definition?

Comment: Please give a complete document that demonstrates the error, and show the full error message from the log from `!` to `?` you have only shown part of the error, which does not show which command is undefined (the last command on the second line of the message)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the style like `style=style1` (not just `style1`). Speaking further, you can use `\surroundwithmdframed[<options>]{environment}` to surround an existing environment with a `mdframed` frame. So to cover `defn` with frame, you need

```
\surroundwithmdframed[style=style1]{defn}
```

Here is a sample.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\mdfdefinestyle{style1}{leftmargin=1cm,rightmargin=1cm,skipbelow=1cm,skipabove=1cm,
   innertopmargin=0pt}
\surroundwithmdframed[style=style1]{defn}
\begin{document}
  \begin{defn}%
(text)
\end{defn}
\end{document}
```

[image]